# Marketing Cloud - Individual Email Results

Tags: email, salesforce, exacttarget

We are having a problem with Individual email results. Our aim is to show individual email results in Salesforce after sending emails from Marketing Cloud.

We sent several emails from Marketing Cloud to the same lead id using template email 'A'. However we noticed that marketing cloud didn't create any individual email results in Salesforce linked to this lead id.
We already verified settings of marketing cloud connector and we didn't find any issue (as a confirm, we sent another email using template email 'B' after the template ‘A’ to the same lead id and IER has been created).

We verified in the Sent Data View (configured using a query) where marketing logs all information related to the email sends and we found out that email sents with template 'A' show the same Job ID, but different Batch ID.

Can the IER creation be affected by this behaviour?

What is the behaviour of Salesforce/Marketing when we have the creation/update of IER? Are there any constraints? (In our example we will probably send the same email template to the same lead id several times in an hour/day).

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) tag.

Comment: Are you sending to Salesforce audiences in SFMC?  Are the send definitions in the Salesforce definition folders?

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs , I confirm that I asked the same question [salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185702/… I am sending to each lead that is injected into a Journey configured in Marketing Cloud. The triggered send has been created in Salesforce and Marketing Cloud after the activation of the Journey. So I am not sending emails to Salesforce Data Extensions or Salesforce Campaigns/Reports